# What does the colon (the pairs of dots) mean in chemical structures?

Tags: molecular-structure, lewis-structure

What do the two dots mean, for example, the "Ö" in [Wikipedia.org - Hydroxonium-cation.svg](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Hydroxonium-cation.svg)

[image]

Comment: 30 characters limit is the system feature against the users who do not bother with topic research before asking nor with the question elaboration. Such questions are almost universally closed as Homework with lack of effort or a post with lack of details. Answering them would increase redundancy of internet.  // Review the guide [How to ask](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) and [Asking FAQs](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/help/asking) to prevent clarification requests, objections,  down-voting or closure.

Comment: Please provide more details. Otherwise, it will be closed as Homework.

Comment: Well, it ain't an umlaut...

Comment: @Mithoron My answer is terse for a reason ...

Comment: @IanBush I was rather intending to criticise the question, than answer. Your post is fine for it, but should be rather a comment. I don't imagine we're gonna keep this q. too long.

Comment: @Mithoron and that's how I took it, no worries

Comment: Actually, I also want to delete it now.

Answer (score 2):

It represents a lone pair of electrons in a [Lewis](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lewis_structure) Structure.